# How to use LiveData with RxSearchView?

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-livedata, rx-binding

I am trying to combine `LiveData` with `RxBinding` library, I want to use `RxSearchView` and use `switchMap` in order to subscribe to the latest observable. I am not sure if my implementation is good. I'll show you my code, please could you tell me if there is another way to achieve this?

```
disposable = RxSearchView.queryTextChanges(searchView)
    .debounce(300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .switchMap(charSequence -> {
      detailViewModel.loadSearchTask(charSequence);
      return Observable.just(charSequence);
    })
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe();
compositeDisposable.add(disposable);

public void loadSearchTask(CharSequence s) {
    taskInteractor
        .search(s.toString())
        .doOnSubscribe(disposable -> rxSearchLiveData.addDisposable(disposable))
        .subscribe(
            charSequence -> rxSearchLiveData.setValue(Resource.success(charSequence)),
            throwable -> error.setValue(Resource.error(throwable.getMessage(), throwable)));
}
```

Edit: Should I use a `Flowable` instead?

Comment: 1.) why are you starting a new observable inside a switchMap, it is supposed to be a pure function 2.) use BehaviorSubject instead of LiveData in this case

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation has several issues. The first one is, that the first `subscribe()` doesn't have any consumers defined. The second one is, that you change the thread while it's not necessary.

The biggest issue I see is, that you're subscribing within a mapping. Instead you should just map to the other `Observable` and handle everything with the single subscription to the chain.

I'll be skipping the `Disposable` handling, so be aware to add it back as necessary.

```
RxSearchView.queryTextChanges(searchView)
    .debounce(300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .switchMap(s -> taskInteractor.search(s.toString()))
    .subscribe(
        charSequence -> rxSearchLiveData.setValue(Resource.success(charSequence)),
        throwable -> error.setValue(Resource.error(throwable.getMessage(), throwable)));
```

As a last note, you can replace the simple lambda `disposable -> rxSearchLiveData.addDisposable(disposable)` with an even more simple method reference `rxSearchLiveData::addDisposable`.